# Creating a Comparison Table from a JQuery JSON Array

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I have jQuery code with an object and a HTML checkbox selection. It's currently giving me separate tables for each selected input but since the keys (row headings) are the same for all, I actually require each selection to appear to the right of the previous selection in a single table.

As such I need to build a simple comparison table to compare each option across parameters. How do I do this?

Image of desired result:

[image]

Awaiting your inputs as I've been  struggling with this code.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var StatJSON = {
    "Opt1": {
      "Name": "Mat",
      "Parameter1": "65",
      "Parameter2": "30"
    },
    "Opt2": {
      "Name": "Mik",
      "Parameter1": "62",
      "Parameter2": "40"
    },
    "Opt3": {
      "Name": "Mir",
      "Parameter1": "65",
      "Parameter2": "90"
    }
  };

  $('#btnSubmit').click(function() {
    var resultString = '';
    $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
      var this_input = $(this);
      if (this_input.is(':checked')) {
        resultString += PrintHtml(StatJSON[$(this).val()]);
      }
    });
    $('#divResult').html(resultString);
  });
});

function PrintHtml(obj) {
  var html = '<div class="opt">';
  if (obj) {
    $.each(obj, function(k, v) {
      html += '<div>' + k + ' : ' + v + '</div>';
    });
  }
  html += '</div>';
  return html;
}
```

```css
.opt {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #222;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Options:
<input type="checkbox" name="Station" value="Opt1">Option1
<input type="checkbox" name="Station" value="Opt2">Option2
<input type="checkbox" name="Station" value="Opt3">Option3
<input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="submit" />
<br /><br />
<div id="divResult"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best way to do it, buy it works just fine!

You should re-structure your data before generating the html, since this approach will not scale well if your data grows too much.

```js
var StatJSON = {
  "Opt1": {
    "Name": "Mat",
    "Parameter1": "65",
    "Parameter2": "30"
  },
  "Opt2": {
    "Name": "Mik",
    "Parameter1": "62",
    "Parameter2": "40"
  },
  "Opt3": {
    "Name": "Mir",
    "Parameter1": "65",
    "Parameter2": "90"
  }
};

$('#btnSubmit').click(function() {
  var data = [];
  $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
    var this_input = $(this);
    if (this_input.is(':checked')) {
      data.push(this_input.val());
    }
  });
  $('#divResult').empty().append(PrintTable(data));
});

function parseData (data) {
  var parsed = {};
  var firstItem = StatJSON[data[0]];
  for (var param in firstItem) {
    parsed[param] = [];
    $.each(data, function(opt) {
      var chosenOpt = data[opt];
      var value = StatJSON[chosenOpt][param];
      parsed[param].push(value);
    });
  };
  return parsed;
}

function cell (str) {
  return '<td>'+str+'</td>';
}

function PrintTable(data) {
  var html = '';
  if (data && data.length) {
    html += '<table class="opt">';
    // 1st row
    html += '<tr>';
    // 1st empty cell
    html += cell('');
    $.each(data, function(index, opt) {
      // each chosen opt
      html += cell(opt);
    });
    html += '</tr>';
    // other rows
    var parsed = parseData(data);
    $.each(parsed, function(param) {
      html += '<tr>';
      // 1st cell
      html += cell(param);
      $.each(parsed[param], function(opt, value) {
        // each param value
        html += cell(value);
      });
      html += '</tr>';
    });
    html += '</table>';
  } else { 
    html = 'No results found'; 
  }
  return html;
}
```

```css
.opt {
  margin: 10px;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #222;
}
.opt td {
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
Options:
<input type="checkbox" name="Station" value="Opt1">Option1
<input type="checkbox" name="Station" value="Opt2">Option2
<input type="checkbox" name="Station" value="Opt3">Option3
<input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="submit" />
</div>
<div id="divResult"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @rafaelcastrocouto, this works!!!! Thanks a million! And, for my knowledge, what would you suggest to be the ideal way to go about this? Thanks again!!!! :)

Comment: Since you asked so nicely I'm updating the answer with some well formatted logic.

Comment: Now you have a `parseData` function that will convert your `StatJSON` in an object with the same structure as your table, this will make easier for you to change this structure in the future. Also I cleaned up the `PrintTable` function in order to make it easier to understand and to edit if required.

Comment: Perfect @rafaelcastrocouto !! I have a looong way to go with learning coding. I needed to identify the table heading and tried replacing the <tr> with <th> in `// 1st row
    html += '<tr>';
    // 1st empty cell
    html += cell('');
    $.each(data, function(index, opt) {
      // each chosen opt
      html += cell(opt);
    });
    html += '</tr>';` but it didn't have the desired effect. I needed to identify the column heading to give it a separate .ccs. How would you suggest I do this? Thanks again, @rafaelcastrocouto for taking the time out for a newbie. :P

Comment: Could you also help me with how to convert the check-box to a 'Select2' multi-select? I wanted the options available to be a dependent drop-down on a previous drop-down option selected. From what I understand this would be difficult with a check-box format. Thanks & many, many thanks again!!!!